# Function Inside a Webjob Not Showing In Dashboard

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I may very well be not understanding how this works, but I thought I was doing pretty good up until now.

I have a Azure Storage Account setup for my WebJob Dashboards.

In the application settings of my WebApp I am setting a Connection String AzureWebJobDashboard of type Custom and it has the connection string to that storage account.

In my Webjob I have the following code:

```
 [FunctionName("ProcessIncomingCustomerQueue")]
        public static void ProcessIncomingCustomerQueue([QueueTrigger("incoming-customer")] string message, ILogger logger)
        {
```

When I start the webjob, is acts like it is finding everything correctly.
No error message about needing to configure the AzureWebJobDashboard.

When it starts it finds the function per the log:
[image]

But when I click on Functions on the top right it says "No functions are present".
Is that not what that is for, to show the functions that are in the webjobs?

Thank you --

Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Functions and Azure Web Jobs are 2 different (but related) technologies. 
Web Jobs run as part of your Web App. Azure Functions are running separate from your Web App.

If you want to have an Azure Function, create a Function App Resource in the Azure portal and use either the Web Portal to write your code or create a Azure Function Project in Visual Studio and deploy it to that resource.
You can also use Visual Studio Code and the Function CLI to create Azure Functions.

Find details and quick starts here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-your-first-function-visual-studio
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function-azure-cli

Comment: That clears it up.  I was confusing functions inside a webjob and Azure Functions!